# Prevent Closing of Windows 7 On-Screen Keyboard

Tags: windows-7, touchscreen, on-screen-keyboard

I'm attempting to create a touchscreen app running on windows 7. I need to be able to prevent the user from closing the on-screen keyboard (or the input panel keyboard, since that's dockable). Are there registry keys or some hidden option to prevent the keyboard from being closed? Or perhaps third-party software that can disable closing of certain apps?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: No answer. Does this mean that it is not possible?

Comment: I never ended up figuring out a way to do it. Eventually, we went with some pretty crappy, specialized kiosk software.